# Redirecionamento pós login no facebook

Tags: facebook, redirecionamento

Olá,
gostariam de tirar uma dúvida sobre o redirecionamento do facebook pós login. Fiz um aplicativo do facebook que o usuário apenas poderá ve-lo quando estiver logado e ele ficará em uma aba. Instalei a aba utilizando Static HTML: iframe tabs. Quando entro na pagina deslogado eu redireciono para o login do facebook. Porém, quando o facebook realiza o redirecionamento ele vai para url onde está a aplicativo e não retorna para aba. Como configuro o callback do facebook para voltar para aba e não para url do iframe?

Algumas observações:

Na meu arquivo resposável pelo login eu coloquei deste modo:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'https:urldoapp.com.br' );
```

Se eu colocar a url da aba ele da erro de redirecionamento não permitindo.
Se eu colocar a url da aba la nas configurações do aplicativo no campo Site URL, o facebook não aceita a url.

Não encontro como fazer a configuração correta. Alguém sabe algum tutorial ou o modo de como fazer isso corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuidado com as URL que utiliza para o facebook verificar, pois nem todas serão aceitas para redirecionamentos.

Tente manipular via JavaScript. Veja isso:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
      FB.init({
          appId: '??????????????', cookie: true,
          status: true, xfbml: true
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
          window.location = "http://example.com";
      });
  </script>
  <fb:login-button>
     Login with Facebook
  </fb:login-button>
```

## Referências:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/